Is there any way to recover deleted Test Suite from Azure Devops?
Was rearranging suites under one test plan. Using Import feature Imported the test suites to a new plan and deleted the Old original test suite. Now Im not able to find the test results in Imported Test Cases.
Is there any way to recover the deleted Test Suites and their associated test results?
Searched in Recycle bin. These seems got deleted permanently.
Is there any way to get them back?

Currently, it doesn't support restoring deleted test suites, whether from the UI or using the REST API. According to this doc,

We only support permanent deletion of test artifacts such as test plans, test suites, test cases, shared steps and shared parameters. Deleted test artifacts won't appear in the recycle bin and cannot be restored. Deletion of test artifacts not only deletes the selected test artifact but also all its associated child items such as child test suites, test points across all configurations, testers (the underlying test case work item doesn't get deleted), test results history, and other associated history.

If you really need to restore deleted test suites, according to Restore deleted test plans and test suites using REST API, you can create a support ticket to contact Azure DevOps team to help you recover.

Currently, we don't have a mechanism to restore accidentally deleted test plans or test suites. To get these restored, you can create a support ticket and our internal teams manually restore these artifacts on your behalf.

